# Being $\frac{Z}{X_{1}}=X_{2}$ , $X_{1}\sim Bin(n,p)$ , $X_{2}\sim Po(\lambda)$, find $P_{Z}(z)$

Tags: probability, statistics

I use probability function method. The first part is finding the joint probability function of  $p_{X_{1}X_{2}}=(x_{1},x_{2})$. This is easy because they are indepentent random variables so this is equal to $p_{X_{1}}(x_{1})p_{X_{2}}(x_{2})$.

Then I define an artificial variable: $U=X_{1}$, then $\rightarrow X_{2}=\frac{Z}{U}$.

Now, I replace the new variables in the joint probability function:

$p_{X_{1}X_{2}}(U,\frac{Z}{U})=\left(\!
    \begin{array}{c}
      n \\
     u
    \end{array}
  \!\right)p^{u}(1-p)^{n-u} \frac{\lambda^\frac{z}{u}}{(z/u)!} $

Then to finish this I have to find the marginal probability function of $Z$, but I don´t know how to solve it.

Also, I find tricky to determinate the support of $Z$.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem setup? $X_1 \sim \text{Binom}(n, p)$ and $X_2 \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ are *independent*, and $Z$ is *defined* as $X_1 X_2$? Or is it that $Z$ and $X_1$ are independent, and $X_2$ is defined as $Z/X_1$?

Comment: $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are independent. $Z$ is defined as $X_{1} X_{2}$. So you have to find the p.d.f of $Z$

Answer (score 1):

Partial attempt, will delete if there is a better answer:

\begin{align}
p_Z(z)
&= \sum_{u=0}^n p_{X_1, X_2}(u, z/u)
\\
&= \sum_{0 \le u \le n \ : \ u \mid z} p_{X_1, X_2}(u, z/u)
\\
&= \sum_{0 \le u \le n \ : \ u \mid z} \binom{n}{u} p^u (1-p)^{n-u} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{z/u}}{(z/u)!}
\end{align}

It seems unclear to me if a simple expression exists. $p_Z(z)$ depends on how many numbers $\le n$ divide $z$, which is not a simple relationship.